# Working with different contexts with JUEL

Tags: java, juel

I was working the expressions and trying to play with the contexts (the one we use at creation time and the one we use at evaluation time). 
Here is some code below that is trying to reproduce my needs and highlight the problem.

```java
    ExpressionFactory factory = new ExpressionFactoryImpl();

    SimpleContext createContext = new SimpleContext();
    createContext.setVariable("myBean", factory.createValueExpression(new MyBean("Laurent"), MyBean.class));

    String expression;
    expression = "${myBean.foo} ${exchange.host}";

    ValueExpression expr = factory.createValueExpression(createContext, expression, String.class);
    System.out.println("expr Class : " + expr.getClass());


    SimpleContext evalContext = new SimpleContext();
    List<String> hosts = asList("www.example.com", "www.foo.com", "www.bar.com");

    // I want to evaluate the same expression, but with different values for the variable exchange.
    for (String host : hosts) {
        evalContext.setVariable("exchange", factory.createValueExpression(new MyExchange(host), MyExchange.class));
        System.out.println(expression + " = " + expr.getValue(evalContext));
    }
```

I setup a basic Maven project on https://github.com/laurentvaills/test-juel-expression to reproduce it .

Can you tell me why I got the following error : `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot find property exchange ?`

Comment: This question was firstly asked as a [Github issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194123/working-with-different-contexts-with-juel) but the author asked me to post such general questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a JUEL issue, but a general EL question. Variables are bound at parse time. Once an expression is parsed, they cannot be changed. At evaluation time, you need to use properties instead:

```
evalContext.getELResolver().setValue(
    evalContext,
    null,
    "exchange",
    new MyExchange(host));
```

See the [documentation for ELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I expected a `setProperty` method.